# how to: Install VSTO addin together with a word template

Tags: ms-word, vsto

I am working on a VSTO addin
I would like how to do that when the addin is going to be installed it's going to install a word template in the template folder together.

Comment: Which Word template folder? The User Templates folder that holds the normal template? The Workgroup Templates folder, that not all users have set up? The Custom Office Templates folder that may or may not be set up? http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fileNew.htm

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to create a custom action for your add-in installer where you could do the required actions programmatically while the add-in is installed.

There are two main ways deploying Office add-ins:

- [Deploy an Office solution by using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2022)
- [Deploy an Office solution by using ClickOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-clickonce?view=vs-2022)

The windows installer (MSI) provides all the necessary tools for that.